# Opening dialog programmatically causes pageInit event to fire

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm opening a dialog programmatically with this piece of code:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#about', {
    transition: 'pop',
    changeHash: false
});
```

`#about` block is on the same page:

```
<div id="about" data-role="dialog">
    <!-- -->
</div>
```

But every time I do that, `pageInit` event is called, which is a very unwanted behavior.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: I believe this is the default behavior as jQM treats the dialog as a page. Even though this is not yet supported you could try http://filamentgroup.com/tests/popup/docs/pages/popup/index.html This was announced on the blog http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by `"which is a very unwanted behavior"` but if you want to only run code once for a dialog then add a check to see if it has been initialized yet:

```
$(document).delegate('#about', 'pageinit', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('ui-dialog') === false) {
        //code in here will only run once per page load/refresh
    }
});
```

jQuery Mobile adds classes to each of the widgets it initializes, you can check the widgets for these classes to test if they have been initialized yet or not.